# Can Maven Failsafe's verify pass only when X percent of integration-tests pass?

Tags: java, maven

I am wondering if there is some way to configure the Maven Failsafe plugin's `failsafe:verify` goal to pass if X% of the tests passed. If not, is there an alternative plugin that can do this?

The idea is to have it fail the build if greater than 10% (for example) of the tests fail.

Comment: Should the threshold be applied to local builds or would be fine if only applied on CI jobs (i.e. on Jenkins)?

Comment: **But why**? What if it is the most critical important test that fails, while the 99% other unimportant pass?

Comment: good point from @Tunaki. Probably a better approach would be to have smoke tests executed firsts and configure the plugin for them (via custom execution and includes on tests suffixes/name patterns). Then also configure [this](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/skip-after-failure.html) option accordingly

Comment: @A. only for CI jobs, these integration tests won't be ran locally as part of the build, they require the application running on a server.

Comment: @Tunaki this is not going to be the yea-or-nay that gets something into production, so a few errors are okay. I understand the concern though. This is going to be used to check of a new commit on develop branch is good enough to be pulled from the CI environment to the QA environment for further inspection and manual tests.